# PHP array_intersect_key but keep values from array2

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = ["b" => "no", "c" => "no", "d" => ["y" => "no"]];
$array2 = ["a" => "yes", "b" => "yes", "c" => "yes", "d" => ["x" => "yes", "y" => "yes", "z" => "yes"]];
```

I want to return the members of `$array2` whose keys are also present in `$array1`.

Desired output:

```
$array3 = ["b" => "yes", "c" => "yes", "d" => ["y" => "yes"]];
```

Basically I need the same functionality as [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) but I want to keep the values from **`$array2`** instead of `$array1`.

Does such a function exist? Also needs to recurse into child arrays. Thanks!

***Edit***
As Andri suggested in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107175/php-array-intersect-key-but-keep-values-from-array2?noredirect=1#comment104445979_59107175), I attempted to flip the arguments around `array_intersect_key($array2, $array1)` but in that case what I actually get is:

```
$array3 = ["b" => "yes", "c" => "yes", "d" => ["x" => "yes", "y" => "yes", "z" => "yes"]];
```

ie *all* the children of "d" just because "d" is mentioned in `$array1`.

Comment: Just swap arguments places in function call ```array_intersect_key($array2, $array1)```

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, but in that case what I actually get is `["b" => "yes", "c" => "yes", "d" => ["x" => "yes", "y" => "yes", "z" => "yes"]];`- ie ALL the children of "d" just because "d" is mentioned in `$array1`

Comment: There is no functions per my knowledge that give you recursive array_intersec_key type ouput. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't as far as I'm aware a built in function, a method using recursion to process all layers should be easy enough...

```
$array1 = ["b" => "no", "c" => "no", "d" => ["y" => "no"]];
$array2 = ["a" => "yes", "b" => "yes", "c" => "yes", "d" => ["x" => "yes", "y" => "yes", "z" => "yes"]];

function intersect_key_2 ( array $a1, array $a2 )   {
    foreach ( $a1 as $key1 => $value1)  {
        // If there is a matching element
        if ( isset($a2[$key1]) )    {
            // Update - if an array, use recursive call else just replace
            $a1[$key1] = ( is_array($value1) ) ? intersect_key_2 ( $value1, $a2[$key1])
                    : $a2[$key1];
        }
    }

    return $a1;
}

print_r(intersect_key_2($array1, $array2));
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [b] => yes
    [c] => yes
    [d] => Array
        (
            [y] => yes
        )

)
```

Comment: SNAP! Haha both came to the same solution, you can have the solve as you were a few seconds before me :P

Answer (score 2):

Ended up writing my own:

```
function array_intersect_key_values_2($array1, $array2) : array {

    $intersection = [];

    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($array2[$key]))
        {
            if(is_array($array1[$key]) && is_array($array2[$key]))
            {
                $intersection[$key] = array_intersect_key_values_2($array1[$key], $array2[$key]);
            }
            else
            {
                $intersection[$key] = $array2[$key];
            }
        }
    }

    return($intersection);
}
```